# No C wire on furnace

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I’m trying to connect a C wire to my Nest Thermostat. However, I’m confused on where to connect it on my furnace seeing that there’s no marked slots on my old furnace. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image][image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: Can you post a make and model, or a wiring diagram for that matter, for your furnace please, or at very least the make and model of the gas valve?

Comment: Sure thing! I just added them.

Comment: Also, one more thing: you have central air, correct?

Comment: Yup! I sure do....

Answer (score 1):

### Cut the red wire going to the A/C, strip the cut ends, and nut the C wire in with them

As it turns out, since you have central air conditioning, finding your C wire isn't that hard after all.  We start with the yellow Y wire from your thermostat, which is connected to the white wire in the cable going off to your condenser (outdoor unit).  From that, since we know that there must be a complete circuit going from the transformer (R wire), through the thermostat to the yellow Y wire, then through the compressor contactor's coil in the outdoor unit, and back to the transformer in the furnace in order for the air conditioning to work when called for, we can infer that the other wire (the red wire) in the cable to the outdoor unit goes to C; in this case, that's a terminal on your furnace's gas valve, which is corroborated by the air conditioner connections shown on your furnace.

As a result of all that, we can treat that red wire as a C wire; however, I'm not sure if you can have multiple wires to a terminal on that gas valve of yours (beyond what's already being done that is), so we need to cut that red wire in two somewhere in the middle, strip both cut ends, and wirenut the blue wire from the thermostat in with the two cut ends to gain access to C on your furnace.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll give that option a shot.

Comment: I was thinking that can't be right! then I realised that gas valve is upside down in the diagram, and you are right.

Comment: For some odd reason it’s providing 24v when I checked it with a volt meter, but it’s still not enough power for the Nest thermostat as it’s still showing low battery. Any other option?

Comment: @StaffordVelasquez -- that's odd, make sure your splice is good and tight, and made up using the correct size wirenut for 3 #18 wires; if that doesn't fix it, you'll need to post a photo of the markings on the furnace's transformer and on the gas valve as well

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel—- I added a picture of my transformer and furnace switch.

Comment: @StaffordVelasquez -- can you not find nameplates/markings on either to get me closeups of?